# Fourier Transform of an image and associated units

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, fft, units-of-measurement, dft

I have the following rather simple problem and unfortunately I am not getting forward.

Imagine a simple 2D image with pixels and a unique value for each pixel of the image.
For example, let the image be 512x512 pixels in size and 10 nm x 10 nm in dimension. Since I want to view the image in frequency space, I calculate the Fourier transform of the image.

Of course, the image still has 512x512 pixels, but what about the units? I would say the physical units are now 1/m, but what happens to the 10 nm?

So what would be the dimensions of my image after the Fourier transform? Would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: perhaps ask this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first frequency bin (after the DC bin) stands for "1 cycle" across the whole domain, so that means 1 / (10 nm) in your case, i.e. wavelength is 10 nm. The pattern continues, next bin stands for 2 cycles, or 2 / (10 nm), i.e. wavelength is 5 nm.

I'm not sure it makes sense to translate the length units in this process.

Comment: If 1 pixel in local space is 10/512 nm in my case, then 1 pixel in frequency space is 1/(10nm*512). Is this correct?
But I am not really sure what you mean by frequency bin.